# Applied Optimization: Find two positive numbers A and B

Tags: calculus

Find two positive numbers $A$ and $B$ (With $A\le B$) who's sum is $80$ and whose product is maximized.
I'm not even sure where to start with this kind of problem.

Comment: Let denote the numbers by $x,y$ and consider the function $f(x,y)=xy.$ Since $x+y=80$ we have $h(x)=f(x,y)=x(80-x)=-x^2+80x.$ You need to find the maximum of this function.

Comment: I got 1600 for the maximum y value by looking at a graph... is this correct? And how would I get it without graphing?

Comment: Graphically, it's a parabola that opens down, so you could find its vertex using elementary algebra, or completing the square.

Comment: I got the wrong answer factoring for some reason

Answer (score 2):

$$A+B=80 \Rightarrow A=80-B$$
$$A \cdot B=(80-B) \cdot B \Rightarrow 80B-B^2$$

$$f(B)=80B-B^2$$

Then find the point at which $f$ achieves its maximum.

**EDIT**: 
$$f'(B)=80-2B$$
$$f'(B)=0 \Rightarrow 80-2B=0 \Rightarrow 2B=80 \Rightarrow B=40$$
$$f'(B)>0 \text{ for } B<40 \text{ and } f'(B)<0 \text{ for } B>40$$

So the function $f(B)=80B-B^2$ achieves its maximum at $B=40$.

(The value of its maximum is equal to $f(40)=1600$)

Then from the relation $A=80-B$, you find the value of $A$, which is:

$$A=80-40=40$$

Therefore, the two positive numbers you are looking for are:
$$A=B=40$$

Comment: I got 1600 for the maximum y value by looking at a graph... is this correct? And how would I get it without graphing?

Comment: I edited my answer..(The maximum you found is correct!)

Comment: Okay! I'm confused, because I tried to factor and got something ridiculous (0 and -80). So now that I have the maximum... How do I use it to find the values of A and B?

Comment: @Natalie: Factoring a polynomial gives you the zeros, not the maximum.

Comment: @Natalie The maximum you found is equal to the product of $A$ and $B$($A \cdot B=\text{ maximum }$).
$$$$
You also know that the sum of $A$ and $B$ is equal to $80$($A+B=80$). Then solve for one variable, for example for $A$, so you get: $$A=80-B$$
You replace this at $$A \cdot B=\text{ maximum }$$ and you get: $$(80-B) \cdot B=\text{ maximum }$$
then solving this equation you get the value of $B$. After that replace this value at $A=80-B$, and you get the value of $A$.

Comment: Okay, so A and B both equal 40. Thank you for helping, it makes sense!